# XCode 4 : error at runtime "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, static, singleton

I develop a static library and build my lib.a.

When I use this library in a iOS project (iPhone app built with -ObjC and -all_load flags for linker), I get this error at runtime :

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This error occurs when I try to call a class method.

```
+ (MyObject *) GetSingleton;
```

For information, I don't get error when I call an instance method.

```
- (void) Log;
```

Have you got an idea of the problem ?

Comment: How are you calling the singleton, exactly?

Comment: I call it by this code line : `[[MyObject GetSingleton] Log];`

Comment: Are you allocating and initializing an instance for the singleton?

Comment: Yes, this is **GetSingleton** implementation : `if (_singleton == nil) { _singleton = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init]; }`

Comment: More information about an issue will be helpful. Provide a bigger piece of a code (better if it will be a header and implementation of your singleton), stack trace with crash and full error with name of method included. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your singleton, try this:

```
+ (MyObject *)GetSingleton {
    static MyObject* singletonInstance; 

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!singletonInstance)
            singletonInstance = [[MyObject alloc] init]; 
    }

    return singletonInstance;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work, still have the same error

Comment: If I don't use static library, and I import my singleton class in my project, there's no problem ! Ha ve you got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I fixed the problem re-creating my project !

I don't know why, my project made bad linking for class method, and not for instance method.

Now, with new project and linkg to my static library, all is OK at runtime.

Maybe it was a problem because of multiples static libraries I built, with probably a bad cache or dependencies...

Thanks for your answers developers !